# Unity3D - вращение объекта

Tags: unity3d

Недавно начал изучать Unity3D, по книге "Unity3D в действии" Джозефа Хокинга. Есть код, который отвечает за вращение капсулы, хотел бы более подробного его объяснения, т.к. в книге не очень понятно.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum RotationAxes
    {
        MouseXAndY = 0,
        MouseX = 1,
        MouseY = 2
    }

    public float sensitivyHor = 4.0f;
    public float sensitivyVert = 4.0f;

    public float minimumVert = -0.90f;
    public float maximumVert = 0.90f;
    private float _rotationX = 0;
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;

    void Update () {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivyHor,0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY)
        {
            _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivyVert;
            _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);

            float _rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, _rotationY, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivyHor;
            _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX,minimumVert,maximumVert);

            float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivyHor;
            float _rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + delta;

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX,_rotationY,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В инспекторе возможно выбрать мод вращения

```
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

// Перечесление. Сделано для более удоного отображения состояния
// вместо 0 1 2, понятен её смысл
public enum RotationAxes
{
    MouseXAndY = 0,
    MouseX = 1,
    MouseY = 2
}
// чувствительности
public float sensitivyHor = 4.0f;
public float sensitivyVert = 4.0f;
// ограничения вращения по Х в градусах
public float minimumVert = -0.90f;
public float maximumVert = 0.90f;
private float _rotationX = 0;
// Выбор типа вращения
public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;

void Update()
{
    // спрашиваем какой стоит мод
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
    {
        // получаем текущей угол поворота по оси Y
        float _rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
        // получаем передвижение мыши по оси Y (0 - 1),
        // домножая на чувствительность получаем изменение угла
        _rotationY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivyHor;
        // получаем текущей угол поворота по оси X
        float _rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
        // Изменяем текущий угол 
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, _rotationY, 0);
    }
    else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY)
    {
        // получаем передвижение мыши по оси Х (0 - 1),
        // домножая на чувствительность получаем изменение угла
        _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivyVert;
        // ограничиваем значение между max и min
        _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
        // получаем передвижение мыши по оси Y (0 - 1)
        float _rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
        // Изменяем текущий угол 
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, _rotationY, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivyHor;
        _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);

        float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivyHor;
        float _rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + delta;

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, _rotationY, 0);
    }
}
}
```